# Azure function written in Python in VS Code works fine on local test but doesn't work on Azure environment

Tags: python, azure-functions

I created a function to fetch data from a SQL server (not Azure SQL database) with Python flask, aimed to create URL with dynamic parameters.

I successfully run the function on local testing in VS Code (with: `func start`).

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pyodbc
import sys
from waitress import serve
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_cors import CORS
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'ppp'

server = 'xxx'
database = 'yield'
username = 'yyy'
password = 'zzz'

app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/yieldrate":{"origins":"*"}, r"/forwardrate":{"origins":"*"}})
logger = logging.getLogger('yieldrate')

def error_handling():
    return 'Error: {}. {}, line: {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1], sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno)


def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    return g.db


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return 'root'


@app.route("/datatable", methods=['GET'])
def get_table():
    out = ''
    query = ''
    try:
        print("")
        query = 'SELECT * from dbo.Libor'

        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        columns = cursor.description

        for row in rows:
            out = out + str(row) + "\n"

        out = str(columns) + " " + out
    except:
        out = "404 : table not found"

    return out

@app.route("/forwardrate/<valuationDate>/<forwardDate>/<tenor>", methods=['GET'])
def get_forward_rate(valuationDate, forwardDate, tenor):
    try:
        query = ''

        formatStr = '%m-%d-%Y'
        dt = datetime.strptime(forwardDate, formatStr)
        resetYear = dt.year
        resetMonth = dt.month

        query = 'SELECT rate FROM dbo.Libor where [valuation date]=convert(DATETIME, \'{valuationdate}\', 101) AND DATEPART(year, [reset date]) = {resetYear} AND DATEPART(month, [reset date]) = {resetMonth} AND [tenor]=\'{tenor}\';'.format(
            valuationdate=valuationDate, resetYear=resetYear, resetMonth=resetMonth, tenor=tenor)
        # query = 'SELECT rate FROM dbo.LiborCurve where [valuation date]= left({valuationDate},2) + \'/\' + substring({valuationDate},3,2) + \'/\' + substring({valuationDate},5,4) AND [reset date]=left({forwardDate},2) + \'/\' + substring({forwardDate},3,2) + \'/\' + substring({forwardDate},5,4) AND [tenor]=\'{tenor}\''

        
        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        if row is None:
            rate = 'No Rate Found!'
        else:
            rate = str(row[0])

        return rate
    except:
        logger.error(error_handling())
        return '!ERROR'



def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.WsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

My function.json code:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "/{*route}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the `"route": "/{*route}"`, it is from some reference which said that I should include this if I am using Python flask with multiple routes.

With this code and running cmd `func start`, I can successfully get result from URL 1, 2:

1. `http://localhost:7071/`: return root
2. `http://localhost:7071/datatable`: return the data in the database

- `http://localhost:7071/forwardrate`: this one is still not working while I input: `http://localhost:7071/forwardrate/09282022/09282022/3`

After I deployed the function to Azure, I got a URL as:
`https://webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/{*route}?`

I tried:
`https://webapi.azurewebsites.net/`: It shows "Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running".

Then I tried:
`https://webapi.azurewebsites.net/api/`: I can't get anything from this, I thought it should return "root" (I thought at least this one should work...).

What happened here, is there any error in my Python code? Or is it caused by my sql server?

I also tried to run the Code + Test directly as

[image]

It doesn't work either...

(I have updated the setting for WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, but I'm not sure why the warning is still there.)

Comment: have you passed auth tokens with the url ?

Comment: No, hmmm, I don't think I should input that, I use "authLevel" : "anonymous". And also in the code, I have tried to set route as "route": "/app/{*route}", but this would fail in my local test. But after I deploy to the cloud, the url automatically include app in url

Answer (score 0):

- In the `function.json` file in the route property instead of the `"/{*route}"` add the route of the function which in your case is `"/datatable"`.

Here I have deployed a function with `"/h"` as route.

**`function.json`**:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
                    {
                        "authLevel": "anonymous",
                        "type": "httpTrigger",
                        "direction": "in",
                        "name": "req",
                        "route":"/h",
                        "methods": [
                                    "get",
                                    "post"
                                    ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "http",
                        "direction": "out",
                        "name": "$return"
                    }
                ]
}
```

- I have also added the following code to the `host.json`:

```
"extensions": {
                "http": {
                            "routePrefix": ""
                        }
}
```

**`host.json` :**

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
                "applicationInsights": {
                                            "samplingSettings": {
                                                                    "isEnabled": true,
                                                                    "excludedTypes": "Request"
                                                                }
                                        }
            },
"extensionBundle": {
                        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
                        "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
                    },
"extensions": {
                "http": {
                            "routePrefix": ""
                        }
                }
}
```

**function code**:  here I make a get request to google and check response.

```
from flask import Flask
import  requests
import  logging
import azure.functions as  func
  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/h', methods=['GET'])
def  call():
    x = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
    if  x.status_code==200 :
        return  "the function is working"
    return  "not working"

  

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return  func.WsgiMiddleware(app.wsgi_app).handle(req)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I tried to change the {*route} to fixed "datatable", it works fine on local, but still failed in cloud :( , and also the reason why I used {*route}, it's because I want the url can be dynamic (as I have route: "datatable" to fetch all data, or "forwardrate/<>/<>" to fetch specific record). I am wondering if it is possible that the fail on cloud may caused by my sql server.

Comment: I tried to use your code/example, and it still works fine locally, but it doesn't work on the cloud : (, Do you have any idea what may happen? Keep getting 500 error

Comment: If you are getting 500 then it is the issue with the internal computation of the server  so check the `monitor` tab in the function it will tell you all the logs. It may a firewall issue on the sql server so check that too